# Kotlin groupBy with range

Tags: android, kotlin

Any method to use groupBy extension function of kotlin with custom range on the selected key 
e.g group all similar items with age less then 2 years apart from each other using list.groupBy{ it.age }

Will iterating the list and writing my own logic the only way for this ?

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to achieve. How would you do that with a simple `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupBy` like this to get items of age between 10 to 15 -

```
val groupedList =  list.groupBy { it.age in 10..15 }
```

Comment: That was helpful, will have to iterate over all age ranges though

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the values first so they can be accumulated in the same group.

```
val groupedList = list.groupBy { it.age / 2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a `Person` class with `age` property, like this-

```
class Person (var age: Int)
```

and you are trying to make groups by 10 years ranges, starting with 0, expecting output like this-

```
{
    0..10=[Person(age=9), Person(age=8)], 
    10..20=[Person(age=15)], 
    20..30=[Person(age=24), Person(age=28)]
}
```

Then your code will be-

```
list.groupBy { (it.age / 10) * 10..(it.age / 10 + 1) * 10 }
```

where you are defining a range based on the `age`. If `age` is anywhere between 0 or 9, the range will be `0..10` and so on.